# SQL Server query case statement inside of a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query to of x people who made y number of orders to provide a histogram. Also Anyone with > 10 orders should be grouped into a “10+” bucket. I do not know how to write a count with a case statement in it.

The table `Orders` has two columns:

```
orderid  int
customerid nchar(5)
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on `CASE` **expressions**? SQL Server doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: Can you show? What about the orders will less than 10?

Comment: Replace `>` with `<` (or perhaps `<=` depending on what you want), or just define the value you want in the `ELSE` @klajdiziaj930 ... You *did* read the linked documentation, right? It tells you the syntax, explains how it works, *and* gives examples. If you show us your attempt, after having a look at those examples, then we can explain where you went wrong.

Comment: Results in ROW or COLUMNS?   Sample data and desired results would reduce assumptions.

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 END)` is pretty standard, there are hundreds of examples of conditional counting online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for two levels of aggregation, with conditional keys on the second:

```
select (case when cnt < 10 then cnt else 10 end), sum(cnt)
from (select customerid, count(*) as cnt
      from orders
      group by customerid
     ) c
group by (case when cnt < 10 then cnt else 10 end)
```

This puts everything with 10 or more into the `10` bucket.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (Y is the number of people who placed X orders where 1 <= X <= 10 or 10+), this should give you what you want. X=11 is your 10+ bucket.

```
With Qry1 As (
    select customerid, count(*) as order_count
    from orders
    group by customerid
), Qry2 As (
    select customerid, 
    case order_count <= 10 then order_count else 11 end as order_count
    from Qry1
)
select order_count As X, count(*) As Y
from Qry2
group by order_count
```